# MySql Stored Procedure, search non printable char in VARCHAR

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Have a MySql stored procedure, input parameter is a VARCHAR(64) which contains non printable ascii character 31 (ascii unit separator) which used as delimiter. In the procedure I want to split the input string by search the delimiter, but don't know how to construct a VARCHAR variable **unitSeparator** that contains the non printable character 31. Following code doesn't work.

```
DECLARE unitSeparator BINARY(10) DEFAULT cast(31 as BINARY);    
SET a = SUBSTRING_INDEX(req, unitSeparator, 1);
SET b = SUBSTRING_INDEX(req, unitSeparator, 2);
SET c = SUBSTRING_INDEX(req, unitSeparator, 3);
```

The procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test(IN req VARCHAR(64))
```

Test by running:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mysql> select char(31);
+----------+
| char(31) |
+----------+
|         |
+----------+
```

See [CHAR()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_char) in the docs.